# RStudio で CSV の dateimport が出来ない

Tags: r, csv, rstudio

csvを指定してdateimorortしようとすると以下のダイアログが表示されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ここでyesを選択するとconsoleの部分に以下のメッセージが表示されます。

```
 file(con, "r") でエラー: unable to translate 'C:/Users/髣夜宦・ｷ譎画､ｪ陝ｶ<8c>/OneDrive/郢・87>郢ｧ・ｹ郢ｧ・ｯ郢晏現繝｣郢・97>/R/tfrfwork (version 1).csv' to UTF-8
```

どうすればデータを取り込めるか教えていただければ助かります。どのCSVでも同じようになります。

Comment: この記事 [第23章 Rのエンコーディング問題](https://shohei-doi.github.io/quant_polisci/encoding-r.html) の「23.1.1 エンコーディング」や「23.4.1 アカウント名が日本語の場合」が関係してそうですね。これらの記事も参考になるかも。[RでCSVファイルの入出力（CP932文字コード指定など）](https://kitamix.net/archives/save-cdv-file-in-r/1096), [R Studioの文字コード設定（Shift-JISからUTF-8など）](https://kitamix.net/archives/default-text-encoding-with-r-studio/900), [日本語データの入ったcsvを読む込む（Windowsの場合）](http://izunyan.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/02/05/122555)

Answer (score 0):

> ここでyesを選択するとconsoleの部分に以下のメッセージが表示されます。

yes を選択しただけでこのようなメッセージが出ることはないと思います. ありえるとすればその後で Data Import で読み込もうとした際のエラーだと思います. そのような仮定で, 現時点での RStudio の最新版 (1.4.1106) を使用していると想定して回答します.

おそらくはファイルパスに英語以外の文字が含まれている時に発生する RStudio の不具合であり, 現時点では解決できません. Data Import を使わず, 直接ファイルパスを入力すればエラーが発生することなくCSVを読み込むことができます.

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", 'Japanese_Japan.932')
library(readr)
data <- read_csv("C:/Users/<あなたのユーザー名>/OneDrirve/<以降のファイルパス>")
```

Tab キーを使えばフォルダ/ファイル名の候補が出てくるため, さほど難しい操作ではないと思います.

一応, ロケールを英語に変えれば このエラーを回避することができますが, 副作用が多すぎるのでおすすめしません.

Answer (score 0):

日本語版 Windows で RStudio をまともに使うのはかなりの地獄なので、
Dockerを用いて コンテナ版 Webアプリ を使うのを強くおすすめします。

使い方は「Docker for Windows」をインストールしたら
以下のコマンドを実行するだけと、とてもカンタンです：

```
docker run -e PASSWORD=yourpassword --rm -p 8787:8787 rocker/tidyverse
```

実行できたら、Google chrome などで `http://localhost:8787/` にアクセスします。

この方法には通常windows上では動作しない fork() を使った並列化ライブラリなども
unix 版と同様に使えるようになるメリットもあります。
環境構築のトラブルがほぼゼロになりますので、ぜひ一度お試し下さい。